# How to Print logs for JUnit test results while an application in build

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I am writing test cases in Junit, and when i build my application, i want to see in my logs which test cases has failed, succeeded , skipped and number of test cases run.

So how can we implement this.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an application you probably run some build tool (Maven, Gradle) to do so.
Maven for example has a plugin (called surefire) for running the tests.
And it also produces a report with all the failures/ successfully run tests.
Since maven also establishes a well-known layout of directories, you'll find this report in the `target/surefire-reports` folder.
There are even tools that can parse the information about the tests execution and show it in a graphical way in CI tools for example